# How can I convert SharePoint hosted app to provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We have a SharePoint hosted app that use some lists and document libraries. We need to convert it to a provider hosted app so we can do some server side actions.

is this feasible? and how?

Answer (score 1):

In your provider-hosted app you can still make use of all your artefacts from your SharePoint-hosted app. I'd suggest you create a new App for SharePoint project for your provider-hosted app, move everything that you want to reuse into your new project and extend your app with your server-side actions.

Comment: But what about the code and pages in my old SharePoint hosted app. I need to reuse the old code and pages

Comment: I don't think you will be able to reuse the code. The biggest difference is that in SharePoint-hosted apps your app works in the context of SharePoint. Provider-hosted apps on the contrary run remotely to SharePoint and therefore they require a different approach than the one you have been using in your SharePoint-hosted app.

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904.aspx): 
Important: You cannot change the app type using the update system. For example, you cannot change an app from SharePoint-hosted to provider-hosted with an update.